# PDF font sizes are off - HTML to PDF via UI/WKWebView and UIPrintPageRenderer

Tags: html, ios, css, pdf, fonts

I need to create nice looking and exact PDFs inside my app. Due to various restrictions, I settled with HTMLs and a custom UIPrintPageRenderer. This works nicely so far.

Yet, due to what I assume are scaling/transformation issues, the resulting font sizes in the PDF are off by quite a margin:

```
#rma {
  font-size: 54pt;
  /*font-size: 67.5px;*/
}
...
<div id="rma">RMA</div>
```

54pt in the CSS results in 57.60pt in the PDF; by using 67.5px instead (wanted pt * 1.25 = px), I can only get it as close as 54.40pt - while feeling like a brute at the same time.

Fiddling around with tenths of a px (or em or anything else), the font size may jump to 53.60pt, but never exactly 54pt. This happens with almost all font sizes, except a few exceptions like 10px resulting in exactly 8pt.

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```

don't seem to have any effect, neither does switching between UI-, WKWebView or UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter. I tried other solutions like brentnycum/BNHtmlPdfKit, with the same effect.

I'm pretty much out of ideas. Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been wrestling with this bug in an iOS app for a long time!

After experimenting, I have filed this as a webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=155789

The PDF font size problems occur when printing from Safari and Chrome as well, but not Firefox. I also ran into this problem in the same way as you, trying to find out why iOS was making PDF's from UIPrintPageRenderer that had weird font sizes.

The best workaround I can provide for you, which I use, is to explicitly set the `<body>` width to the exact page width.

```
body {width: 595pt;}
```

This has enabled me to get font sizes specified as 12pt out at 12.01pt - but it does vary depending on some (seemingly) random factors. Best of luck!

Comment: Looks like there's two of us, then! Thanks for your help - while it doesn't fix the scale 100%, it's pretty close. I'm using mustache internally, so it should be possible to still have those calculated dynamically; i now use (width - 2*insetY), since I'm calculating insets for all the printable borders. So right now that would be (595.2-15*2)pt. Before your comment, I fiddled with negative margins and equal positive paddings to change the zooming factor (which I would assume is the problem here), but that seemed rather random and changed different font sizes in different ratios.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use php this should do the trick

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a possibility - I use Mustache for preprocessing purposes, but other than that php isn't going to help here, but thanks.